# $Df(x)=L$ iff there is a $c\in \mathbb R^p$ with the trait that $f(x)=L(x)+c $

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^p$ be a totale differentiable
>   function and $L: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^p$ a linear
>   function. Prove the following are equivalent.
>
> a)For every $x\in \mathbb R^n$ is $Df(x)=L$
>
> b)There is a $c\in \mathbb R^p$ with the trait that $f(x)=L(x)+c $  for
>   every $x\in\mathbb R^n$

I got stuck proving $a$ implies $b$.  My idea was to use something that we've proved earlier.

> Let $f: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be partialy differentiable
>   to every variable and let grad$f(x)=0$ for every $x\in\mathbb R^n$
>   then $f$ is constant.

I wanted to show that from  a we can see that the grad$f(x)-L=0$, thus $f(x)-L$ is a constant, which is the same as $f(x)=L(x)+c$.

I think I should be able to show this, but I'm not sure how to do it.
A little nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated :)

**Edit**

Let $g(x)=f(x)-L(x)$

grad$g(x)=(\frac{\partial g}{\partial x_1},..., \frac{\partial g}{\partial x_n})$
$$=(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1},...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}-\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_n})$$

Because $Df(x)=L$, we get $D_1f(x)=L_1$ so grad $g(x)=(0,...,0)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f(x)-Lx$. Verify from definition that $Dg(x)=0$ for all $x$. This implies that $g$ is a constant $c$ so $f(x)=Lx+c$.